# bash while loop and the file handle for read

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand a little more on the bash shell while loop.

**Method 1:**  `while read < myfile LINE; do echo $LINE; done`
**Method 2:**  `while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done < myfile`

Method 1 reads only the first line from myfile each time the loop iterates.

Method 2 reads the next line each time the loop iterates.

And I assume the reason is, in method 1, input redirection (`<`) is executed each time the loop iterates, where the file handle is closed and opened each time.

My question to you is, how do I investigate this at the shell, and where can I find more such details on shell.

Comment: You will want to read [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents), the [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Answer (score 0):

> **Method 1:** `while read < myfile LINE; do echo $LINE; done`

Just to break down what is happening: The LINE command copies the first line from standard input, so in this case it will copy the first line of "myfile". It will then send the output to the READ command. The pass condition of this while loop is for something to be READ so as long as something is being passed to READ the while loop will run. Therefore if "myfile" is empty or does not exist the while loop will stop or not run to begin with. $LINE will hold the value of the first line in "myfile" so every time the while loop runs it prints only the first line.

> **Method 2:** `while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done < myfile`

This might make more sense to you now. You direct "myfile" to be READ by LINE as the while loop condition rather than in method 1 your while condition was to READ the first line of "myfile" only.

You should use the MAN command to get the manual page of a command to find more about it.

```
$ man line
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/line.1.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Another online tool you can use to see what is going on is https://explainshell.com/

Comment: Jake's note about Method1 is incorrect. The line command is not used.

Comment: But if you run: 'while read < myfile ; do echo $LINE; done'
The first line is not returned of myfile just a blank line, can you elaborate ?

Comment: Looks like you made a typo when quoting the Method1. The Method1 should run an infinite loop, just printing the first line every time, unless the myfile is empty.